# nmap program was not found in path

Tags: python-3.x, nmap

i am trying to use the 'nmap' module in python.i am using windows, pycharm, python 3.6.i installed the `python-nmap` module(installing 'nmap' module was showing the error: `nmap has no attribute called 'PortScanner'`)  directly from inside the pycharm. I tried like 4 hours. cant solve this issue.

```
import nmap
ns = nmap.PortScanner()
```

running this gives the following error:

```
nmap.nmap.PortScannerError: "nmap program was not found in path. PATH is : 
C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\iCLS 
Client\\;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\iCLS 
Client\\;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\DAL;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\IPT;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\DAL;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\IPT;C:\\Users\\Tanmay's\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32"
```

i'm new with python and nmap.. your help would be really appreciated.

Comment: And yes i have tried everything possible.(editing the path, making the environment varible, looking on internet for solution..but no luck.

Comment: Did you install `nmap`, not just the lib?

Comment: Is the nmap directory listed on the error message? If not try adding the nmap dir to the path via python (i.e. import sys; sys.path.append('path/to/nmap') )

Comment: Still the same error.. @Davide

Comment: How do i install nmap?? isn't it a module that can be added directly? can you tell me the whole process of setting up the nmap,  please? @Càphêđen

Comment: nmap is a separate program that looks like you haven't installed... [nmap download page](https://nmap.org/download.html)

Comment: Sorry, i didn't know  that nmap is a separate program..installed it and it's working fine now.. very much thank you buddy @Davide